# Shopify - Liquid - {% if form.posted_successfully? %} not working for Register Customer Module

Tags: php, html, shopify, liquid

i had to include the register form in password.liquid ( Shopify ).. The form works but no success message appears after form is processed ... Acording to the documentation it should work ..hmmm help ?

```
 {% form 'create_customer', class: 'customer-register' %}


   {% if form.posted_successfully? %}
   <div>Thank you for your enquiry! We will get back to you as soon as possible!</div>
  {% else %}
    {{ form.errors | default_errors }}
  {% endif %}



     <div id="naeark">New Account Enquiry</div>
     <div id="naetark">To get started as a Plum & Ashby stockist, please tell us a little about your store!</div>



      <input type="text" id="arkfn" placeholder="First Name" value="{{ form.first_name }}" name="customer[first_name]" class="{% if form.errors contains "first_name" %}error{% endif %}">

      <input type="text" id="arkln" placeholder="Last Name" value="{{ form.last_name }}" name="customer[last_name]" class="{% if form.errors contains "last_name" %}error{% endif %}">

      <input type="text" id="arkmail" placeholder="Email" value="{{ form.email }}" name="customer[email]" class="{% if form.errors contains "email" %}error{% endif %}">


    <input id="telephone"  type="text" name="customer[note][Telephone]" placeholder="Telephone" />

    <input id="website"  type="text" name="customer[note][Website]" placeholder="Website" />

    <input id="storename"  type="text" name="customer[note][StoreName]" placeholder="Store Name" />

    <input id="streetaddress1"  type="text" name="customer[note][StreetAddress]" placeholder="Street Address" />

    <input id="streetaddress2"  type="text" name="customer[note][StreetAddress2]" placeholder="Street Address 2" />

    <input id="City" type="text" name="customer[note][City]" placeholder="City" />

    <input id="state-region" type="text" name="customer[note][state-region]" placeholder="State/Region" />

    <input id="Country" type="text" name="customer[note][Country]" placeholder="Country" />

    <input id="Zip-PostalCode" type="text" name="customer[note][Zip-PostalCode]" placeholder="Zip/Postal Code" />

      <div id="ATCont">
        <div class="titleat">Account Type</div>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Brick & Mortar Retailer" name="customer[note][BMR]" id="BMR" />
        <label for="BMR" class="login labelark">Brick & Mortar Retailer</label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Online Retailer" name="customer[note][OR]" id="OR" />
        <label for="OR" class="login labelark">Online Retailer</label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Rep/Distributor" name="customer[note][RD]" id="RD" />
        <label for="RD" class="login labelark">Rep/Distributor</label>

      </div>


     <input id="Question" type="text" name="customer[note][Question]" placeholder="Question/Comment" />

      <input id="arkpwd" type="password" placeholder="Password" value="" name="customer[password]">

    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="submit" value="{{ 'customers.register.submit' | t }}">
    </div>
            {% endform %}
  {% endif %}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `form.posted_successfully?` isn't set to true when a customer is created.  Instead, you get an "error" stating "We have sent an email to someone@example.com, please click the link included to verify your email address"

You may be able to parse that string out of the errors to detect successful form submissions.